# sockets in servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, client

I have a java client that sends a message to the server .The server is a servlet deployed on jboss. My question is can the servlet send data back to the client as acknowledgment? is it possible in servlets?

Answer (score 2):

From [Java EE 5 tutorial chapter 4](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafe.html):

> #### What Is a Servlet?
>
> A servlet is a Java programming language class that is used to extend the capabilities of servers that host applications accessed by means of a request-response programming model. Although servlets can respond to any type of request, they are commonly used to extend the applications hosted by web servers. For such applications, Java Servlet technology defines HTTP-specific servlet classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with servlets. Read the basics [here](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/Servlet-Basics.pdf).

Comment: In the link that you sent all the examples use a html form as the client that calls the servlet. I have a standalone java program as my client. can i call the servlet from the client and exchange data between these two.

Comment: @AshwinBhaskar Yes you can call the sevlet from client using URLConnection class. Here is the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible; a servlet that didn't have the ability to send data back to the client wouldn't be very useful.

There are many ways to do so but the most "raw" way is by writing to `ServletResponse.getOutputStream()`.  The `ServletResponse` is passed to the `service` method of a `Servlet` implementation.  Note that the data is of course going to be sent back as a valid HTTP response (identified using MIME, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Ashwinm if you are looking for posting a result to a socket (on client) and not returing the result through mormal HTTP response.

Which I believe is not a servlet question then.  You can anyway do anything in java. But have to look at normal "how to write to a socket" tutorial.

GenreicServlet might provide some extensibility or some solution.

**EDIT**

I read your commentes below later. Yes you need URLConnection in that case at the bare minimum.

Answer (score 1):

An http servlet works on http request and can send back the http response. You can connect to it using URLConnection as described above.

If you don't want to get at this level (layer), you can work at with the packets directly (using sockets). Here you dont need a servlet actually. Here your server (a simple java application) will listen on a socket for any incoming connection and the client can connect to it.